# Gravitee APIM login with AM (Gravitee.io)

Tags: gravitee

Not able to login with AM OAuth2

On Gravitee AM

1. created application with redirect uri: https://localhost:8084
2. created inline providers with user

On Gravitee APIM

1. organization - Authentication - added the identity provider with Gravitee.io AM

- provided domain
- provided client I’d and client secret

This is my APIM URL
https://localhost:8084
when I login with identity provider, it is taking back to again login page instead of log into the APIM.

Error message: session expired, redirected to home.

This is weird but I tried with Google identity provider which is worked perfectly.

Can anyone please help me